# Using variations of the `dayPeriod` option in Intl.DateTimeFormat always returns the same value

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, intl

MDN says about `dayPeriod`,

> The formatting style used for day periods like "in the morning", "am", "noon", "n" etc. Possible values include: "narrow", "short", "long".

Options such as `weekday` return distinct values for "narrow", "short", and "long" (e.g. "M", "Mon", "Monday").

When I use these options for `dayPeriod` I always get the same result.  Local time right now is 9:57 am.  Every option for `dayPeriod` is returning "in the morning".

```js
let intl = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {
  hourCycle: 'h12',
  dayPeriod: 'narrow'
});

console.log(intl.format(new Date())); // "in the morning"
```

I would expect the `long` option to return "in the morning".  I would expect the `short` option to return "morning".  I would expect the `narrow` option to return "m" or "am".  Instead, "in the morning" is always returned.

Comment: MDN also notes: "that for many locales the strings are the same irrespective of the value passed for the dayPeriod"

Comment: The formats produced by *toLocaleString* are entirely implementation dependent, though they are asked to follow formats suggested for particular languages by the [*CLDR Project date/time charts*](https://unicode-org.github.io/cldr-staging/charts/latest/verify/dates/index.html) and the rules in [*ECMA-402*](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-402/) (which can be difficult to decipher correctly).

Comment: Oh, the [CLDR date/time chart for language en](https://unicode-org.github.io/cldr-staging/charts/latest/verify/dates/en.html) specifies "in the morning" for wide, abbreviated and narrow (which don't exactly correlate to [ECMA-402's](https://402.ecma-international.org/9.0/#sec-datetimeformat-abstracts) "narrow", "short" and "long"), so I guess implementations are just following the CLDR. You can make suggestions as to what you think it should be.